# concatenate two input elements in an input-group div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a `select` and an `input` element next to each other in an `input-group` (and on the same line). Here's what I've currently got: http://bootply.com/95860

I've tried a few combinations of `.input-addon`, `<span>` containers, and plenty more. I was able to do this in bootstrap 2, and got a semi-decent result (not using inputs, but selects), as you can see here: http://puu.sh/5p9XU.png (the example is a bit different, but the premise is the same).

Comment: First of all as clearly stated in the documentation you should avoid using select elements as they cannot be fully styled on web-kit browsers like Chrome or Safari. Second of all it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Is it something like this? http://bootply.com/95862

Comment: I know they should be avoided, but I'm not really sure of any alternatives to what I'm trying to accomplish with it. I could use 5 buttons, but I think that would take up more space. Yes, that is like that - I just want the two elements attached together as well.

Comment: As in so? http://bootply.com/95864

Comment: Yes. Would you have any alternative ideas to using a <select>? I just need to show a static list of items: <, <=, =, =>, > and I suppose <select> might not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the drop down from the bootply in the comments but instead implement the click event of the elements to display what you need:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('button').html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

This is just an idea, but keep in mind that bootstrap will not ever have 100% of the things you can think of, so you can adapt it to fit your needs with jQuery. http://bootply.com/95871

Comment: Thanks. I was just making sure there definitely wasn't a built-in way to handle this, because I was scratching my head for a while. I appreciate the time you've put forth into helping me figure this out, thanks!